# Steps to go from $\frac{\frac{1}{x}-y}{\frac{1}{x}+y}$to $ \frac{1-xy}{1+xy} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What are the steps involved in simplifying:
$$
\frac{\frac{1}{x}-y}{\frac{1}{x}+y}
$$
into
$$
\frac{1-xy}{1+xy}
$$

Comment: Simplify[((1/x) - y)/((1/x) + y)] works

Comment: Are we sure this is related to *Mathematica* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{\frac{1}{x}-y}{\frac{1}{x}+y}=\frac{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{xy}{x}}{\frac{1}{x}+\frac{xy}{x}}=\frac{\frac{1-xy}{x}}{\frac{1+xy}{x}}=\frac{1-xy}{1+xy}$$

Comment: @joshmyers, you are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply multiply the numerator and the denominator by $x$.